# Finding the angle between the negative y-axis and the cross product of two vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm trying to help a friend with the following homework question:

Vectors A and B lie in an xy plane. A has a magnitude of 8.00 units and an angle of 130 degrees; B has components Bx = -7.72 units and By = -9.2 units. Find the angle between the negative direction of y-axis and the direction of the product AxB.

Now I have already calculated B have an angle of 230.11 degrees. I can calculate the angle between the two vectors using the dot product method, but the question asked for the angle between the negative y-axis and the ***cross-product*** of the two vectors, the cross-product being a vector that is both perpendicular to both A and B, which is causing a problem for me. Can somebody give me some help in resolving this particular issue? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Think of any vector lying on the $y$-axis (pointing in the negative direction) and calculate the dot product between this and $A\times B$.

Comment: @draks - But wouldn't the cross-product of A and B be normal to the x-y plane?

Comment: right. So the angle is $\pi/2$, as in Ross' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question as given is indicated in your comment.  The cross product of any two vectors in the $xy$ plane (unless they are parallel) is in the $\pm z$ direction.  Its angle with the negative $y$ axis (or any vector in the $xy$ plane) is $\frac \pi 2$.

Comment: Thanks Ross!! I guess I was thinking about the question too hard and ignoring some of the principles...thanks for pointing them out. Much appreciated!!! :)